# How to choose interface while creating a docker network?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I've created a network interface and some chains for it in iptables and want to use it in single `docker run`. It's pretty easy to [do that](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/build-bridges/) for all the containers. Also, it's possible to run containers in different networks.

How can I use different interfaces in different docker networks?

If it's not possible, how can I use different firewalls for different docker containers?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

Comment: can't find a flag for choosing interface there

Answer (score 0):

With docker bridge, we dont get chance to choose the underlay interface. The underlay interface is chosen based on route table. We can create a new bridge and use that bridge, this is what user defined bridge does. For choosing a specific underlay interface, we need to use drivers like macvlan.